# Restlet Getting HTTP Status code 204 instead of 200

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet

For the 1st request, I get the JSON response. From the next request onwards I start getting this log and HTTP Status Code 204, even though the ServerResource is successfully returning a representation

```
org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerAdapter commit
WARNING: A response with an unavailable and potentially non empty entity was returned. Ignoring the entity for resource http://localhost:8888/xyz?abc=def
```

Application class for wiring routes

```
@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    router = new Router(getContext());
    CorsService corsService = new CorsService();         
    corsService.setAllowedOrigins( new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("http://example.com")));
    corsService.setAllowedCredentials(true);
    getServices().add(corsService);
    router.attach("/xyz", XYZ.class);
}
```

Server Resource which handles and returns a JSON Representation

```
public class XYZ extends ServerResource {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("API:XyZ");

    @Get(":json")
    public Representation handleGetRequest() {
         ..
         return API_RESPONSE_JSON_REPRESENTATION_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After releasing the response, the representation state `available` is set to false. So subsequent calls to the `ServerResource`, returns the Representation but in `handle()` method it is set to 204 since `getResponseEntity().isAvailable()` returns `false`.

From `ServerResource`:

```
@Override
public Representation handle() {
       ...
        } finally {
            if (Status.CLIENT_ERROR_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.equals(getStatus())) {
                updateAllowedMethods();
            } else if (Status.SUCCESS_OK.equals(getStatus())
                    && (getResponseEntity() == null || !getResponseEntity()
                            .isAvailable())) {
                getLogger()
                        .fine("A response with a 200 (Ok) status should have an entity. "
                                + "Changing the status to 204 (No content).");
                setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_NO_CONTENT);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Either return a new representation every time or setAvailable to true before returning the representation