# Restlet Server 204 issue

Tags: java, rest, restlet

I am facing really strange issue with my Restlet server.
I have setup a simple Restlet server for Mocking purpose. In this server I have defined a Get and one Put method. I am running the server on localhost at some particular port.
The issue is that I am able to get the Get response in my local but when deployed in Dev env, I get 204 message. 
From the logs I see it does not even goes to my Get method and just return 204 message.
I am really confused why it is not going inside the Get method.
Inside Get method the first line is a log statement.

The Get method return a Person java object. It is something like this

```java
@Get
public Person getPerson() {
   // log
   return new person("A", 23);
}
```

When it is not going to Get method why it is giving me 204. Any advice on this issue?

Comment: Could you add more details? What do you mean by **local** and **dev**?
Please provide all the steps you did that led to the issue (How you application configuration looks like? How are you running your application? How did you switch to another environment? How are you calling your application endpoints?)

Comment: You shall remote debug your Dev env.

Comment: Possibly copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975772/restlet-getting-http-status-code-204-instead-of-200